# Missing contents in .txt file after shutil.make_archive

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

```
Sysinfo = open('SystemInformation.txt', 'w')
Sysinfo.write("something useful",)
Sysinfo.close

#a handful more processes occur here

os.chdir(dstFolder)
shutil.make_archive('filename', 'zip', srcFolder)
```

I have the above code and everything zips up just fine except for the SystemInformation.txt file I created. When I open it up after extracting the .zip file it is completely blank. The odd part to me is that the same file in the source folder before it gets zipped is completely fine.

Comment: Maybe you should use `Sysinfo.close()` instead of `Sysinfo.close`?

Comment: d'oh! wow... Thank you so much mkrieger1!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you call functions properly. You are missing the following:

```
Sysinfo.close()
```